# Memory sanitizer reports use-of-uninitialized-value in global object construction

Tags: c++, constructor, clang, global, msan

I get `use-of-uninitialized-value` warning while executing the following program compiled with `clang++-9 -fsanitize=memory`:

```cpp
#include <map>

class msan_test
{
  std::map<int, int> m_map;

public:
  msan_test()
  {
    m_map.insert(std::make_pair(1, 1));
    m_map.insert(std::make_pair(2, 2));
  }
};

msan_test gobj; // global object of above class

int main()
{
  return 0;
}
```

This is the warning I get:

```
==16598==WARNING: MemorySanitizer: use-of-uninitialized-value
    #0 0x49898f in std::_Rb_tree<int, std::pair<int const, int>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<int const, int> >, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int const, int> > >::_M_get_insert_unique_pos(int const&) (/home/noname/a.out+0x49898f)
    #1 0x49828e in std::pair<std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<int const, int> >, bool> std::_Rb_tree<int, std::pair<int const, int>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<int const, int> >, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int const, int> > >::_M_emplace_unique<std::pair<int, int> >(std::pair<int, int>&&) (/home/noname/a.out+0x49828e)
    #2 0x497a7e in std::enable_if<is_constructible<std::pair<int const, int>, std::pair<int, int> >::value, std::pair<std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<int const, int> >, bool> >::type std::map<int, int, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int const, int> > >::insert<std::pair<int, int> >(std::pair<int, int>&&) (/home/noname/a.out+0x497a7e)
    #3 0x49785a in msan_test::msan_test() (/home/noname/a.out+0x49785a)
    #4 0x41be52 in __cxx_global_var_init (/home/noname/a.out+0x41be52)
    #5 0x41beb8 in _GLOBAL__sub_I_memsan.cpp (/home/noname/a.out+0x41beb8)
    #6 0x49bcbc in __libc_csu_init (/home/noname/a.out+0x49bcbc)
    #7 0x7f5db517db27 in __libc_start_main /build/glibc-OTsEL5/glibc-2.27/csu/../csu/libc-start.c:266
    #8 0x41bee9 in _start (/home/noname/a.out+0x41bee9)

SUMMARY: MemorySanitizer: use-of-uninitialized-value (/home/noname/a.out+0x49898f) in std::_Rb_tree<int, std::pair<int const, int>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<int const, int> >, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int const, int> > >::_M_get_insert_unique_pos(int const&)
Exiting
```

Is this a false positive or something deep is going on?

Thanks.

Comment: The canonical answer to this would be "don't use global variables, ever" I suppose.

Comment: @idclev463035818 You can reproduce it becasuse of godbolt.  coliru reproduces the results: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2f8fbd89d661fb76

Comment: I'm going to say this is a false positive.

Comment: @NathanOliver I was suspecting that, but wasnt sure.

Comment: @idclev463035818 I have removed `// use gobj`.  @NathanOliver is there any reason why memory sanitizer is producing a false positive?

Comment: Looks like this might answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47486755/clang-memory-sanitizer-reports-use-of-uninitialized-value

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz While globals should be avoided, the sanitiser is triggered even if you use a local.

Comment: fwiw, initializing the map instead of using `insert` yields the same warning: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/59958135c0b1f936

Comment: Sorry, wrong link.  See: https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2/issues/899 also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46930744/using-memory-sanitizer-instrumented-libc also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20617788/using-memory-sanitizer-with-libstdc

Comment: This shorter example without globals also generates `use-of-uninitialized-value` warning: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/26452112448b24fe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably already reported MemorySanitizer bug https://github.com/google/sanitizers/issues/542.

However it was closed with Status WontFix without much explanation.

It seems that you need to build instrumented C++ standard library to avoid false positives. From [MemorySanitizer wiki](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/MemorySanitizerLibcxxHowTo):

> If you want MemorySanitizer to work properly and not produce any false
>   positives, you must ensure that all the code in your program and in
>   libraries it uses is instrumented (i.e. built with -fsanitize=memory).
>   In particular, you would need to link against MSan-instrumented C++
>   standard library. We recommend to use libc++ for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this a false positive or something deep is going on?

Either this is false positive in the sanitiser, or the standard library implementation has a bug.

There is no reading of uninitialised value in the shown program.

Comment: Not necessarily. For example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3246008/c-strings-strlen-and-valgrind